# Generate a unique number/value for a column that does not have UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions

I am having this Entity (both in database and Entity Framework):

```
public class LanguageValue
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public long Key { get; set; } // bigint in database
    public int LanguageID { get; set; } // FK with a Language table in database
    public string Value { get; set; } // nvarchar(MAX) in database
    public bool Active { get; set; } // bit in database
}
```

I have already read this article, but my problem is a bit different: [EF6: How to generate a unique number automatically based on entity Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754882/ef6-how-to-generate-a-unique-number-automatically-based-on-entity-id)

My `Key` column does not have unique constraint, because there can be multiple rows with the same `Key` value. For example:

```
ID   Key   LanguageID    Value
---------------------------------------------------
1    1     1             Name in Language 1
2    1     2             Name in Language 2
```

I cannot use a Mapping table to enforce a FK instead of `Key` because multiple tables uses this same table (Product's Name, Category's Name, Article's Content).

Now whenever I need to insert a `Product` or `Category` record, I need to insert their corresponding Language Value. However, I have yet to find a way to generate a Key that is unique among them, and more over, need to be unique in case two insert are being processed at once (for example, adding a Product and Category at the same time).

I am thinking about `Guid`, should that be my safe bet with RNG, or is there any better way/design for achieving it?

Comment: ID is your unique identifier.. how is that different from what you're wanting to do?

Comment: For every Insert operator, I need to insert 2 rows (or more depends on how many language), with the same `Key`, but except those 2 rows, no other row may have that `Key` value. So it is not the ID.

Comment: And I would like to insert all `Product` and its 2 `LanguageValue` records in one transaction, so in EntityFramework, I do not have the ID yet.

Comment: Well guid would work if you're not willing to create new entities like `ProductLanguages, CategoryLanguages`, etc..

Comment: another option would be to add nullable foreign key fields to your LanguageValue entity for each of the different entity types

Comment: @JamieD77 I have considered that option, but it would waste too much space when the number of entities increase. However, I am now trying another solution I just think about. I am creating a `LanguageKey` table instead (which act as the current key), and a real `LanguageValue` table and have FK with the `LanguageKey` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think my problem was from bad database design. I seperated the `LanguageValue` table into two tables, like the following diagram, and realize 2 pros that the previous design did not have:

[image]

1. I can now safely insert the `LanguageKey` with `IDENTITY`.
2. I can now have FK for Product and Category's `NameLanguageKey`, which were impossible before because `Key` was not unique.

Comment: glad you found a good result. btw - imho, by only presenting the LanguageValue table/class in your OP, i think you obscured your problem. the above extended diagram explains far better what you were after.. anyway, plus 1 for sharing the final solution